# Return the total of a group with Jinja

Tags: django, jinja2

I have an object to return by group and then display the number of grouped items. example :

```
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>>
            {% set count = 0 %}
            {% for item in data.items|groupby(attribute="name") %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ item.grouper }}</td>
              <td>{% for number in item.list %}{% set count = count + 1 %}{{ count }}{% endfor %}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

I also tried :

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>>
        {% for item in data.items|groupby(attribute="name") %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.grouper }}</td>
          <td>{% for number in item.list %}{{ loop.length }}{% endfor %}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

But the return for a total of 3 is: "111" or "333" and i want display "3",
avez-vous une idée ?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful in jinja the "+" is for concatenation not for addition. For that there is a filter |add but right now if I understand what you want you don't need that:

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>>
        {% for item in data.items|groupby(attribute="name") %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.grouper }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.list|length }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Would be enough

Comment: Ahhhhh... Yes it's good ! (Thank U) Is it possible to retrieve the value of "item.list|length" to use it in a new column? (to display a percentage of items by group).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>"Name"</th>
          <th>"Total"</th>
          <th>"%"</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% set total = data.items|length %}
        {% for item in data.items|groupby(attribute="name") %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item.grouper }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.list|length }}</td>
          <td>{{ total*(item.list|length)*0.1 }}{{ "%" }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```